# Count using read() method in java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Enter");

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    {
        int c;
        int count = 0;
        while ((c = input.read()) != -1) {

            System.out.println(+count);
            count++;

        }

    }
}
```

Using the read() method only I want to print the count of each char, Eg: if my input:the star then output should be: 9, but when I try to put the count outside the loop my program never comes out of loop and print the total count value, readline(), next(), hasnext() methods doesn't count char by char so they give me a wrong result

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop never exits because the `read` method never returns `-1`. It only does that when the stream reaches *end of file* (EOF). The underlying stream that the `BufferedReader` uses (`System.in`) has to be closed in order for that to happen.

I'm not sure what your requirements are but if you're looking to read one line of input from the console and determine how many characters that line has, you could do something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = sc.readLine();
int charCount = line.length();
System.out.println("Characters count: " + charCount);
```